# How to fill dropdownlist from database based on selected item of another dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a SQL table named doctor search and have 2 dropdownlists one shows expertise of the doctor and i want to fill dropdownlist 2 with the information of those doctor which are related to that expertise section.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily if you are using the designer interface.
    Try using the below code after making necessary changes (Connection String, Table name and Column name). If that doesn't work, I will share the steps

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Your Connection String %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Expertise] FROM [Your Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpertise" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Expertise" DataValueField="Expertise">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Your Connection String %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [DoctorDetails] FROM [Your Table] WHERE ([Expertise] = @Expertise)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlExpertise" DefaultValue="" Name="Expertise" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDoctorDetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="DoctorDetails" DataValueField="DoctorDetails">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It works fine for first time, when I change the selected value in ddlexpertise then the values in ddldoctordetail doesn't change. please reply me with a suitable answer.

Comment: Try giving autopostback true for  ddlexpertise

Comment: If the answer was helpful then please up wote it :)